# Word wrap on report lab PDF table

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm using the Table of Report Lab library to print a table on a PDF report. I would like to know if it's possible to configure the table to perform an automatic wrapping of the content of a cell.

For example, I have a text that doesn't fit on a cell inside a column. I would like that the table performs the wrap automatically adjusting the content of the cells to fit on the columns width. Is it possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can put any flowable in a table element.  It is probably good practice to have all table elements as flowables, so they can be styled the same.  For your case you will most likely need a Paragraph flowable. eg.

```
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
text = Paragraph("long line",
              styles['Normal'])
```

You can put `text' into the data you feed to a table and it will automatically wrap.

Comment: I test it now and it really works, wrapping by word. Thanks man!

Comment: I have a problem after using this..if the data is longer and takes second line to fit in then my other cell data also starts from the second line now and first line for these cells remains empty. Can you help with this? Making my other cell data not shift to second line for start instead

Answer (score 2):

My solution, force newline in the string:

```
def __chopLine(line, maxline):

    cant = len(line) / maxline
    cant += 1
    strline = ""
    index = maxline
    for i in range(1,cant):
        index = maxline * i
        strline += "%s\n" %(line[(index-maxline):index])
    strline += "%s\n" %(line[index:])
    return strline
```

Answer (score 1):

*whole code of word wrap

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER
from reportlab.lib import colors

# bodytext  style used for wrapping  data on flowables 
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
styleN = styles["BodyText"]
#used alignment if required
styleN.alignment = TA_LEFT

styleBH = styles["Normal"]
styleBH.alignment = TA_CENTER


hdescrpcion = Paragraph('''<b>descrpcion</b>''', styleBH)
hpartida = Paragraph('''<b>partida</b>''', styleBH)


descrpcion = Paragraph('long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long line ', styleN)
partida = Paragraph('1', styleN)

data= [[hdescrpcion, hpartida],
       [partida ,descrpcion]]

table = Table(data)

table.setStyle(TableStyle([
                       ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ]))

c = canvas.Canvas("a.pdf", pagesize=A4)
table.wrapOn(c, 50, 50)
table.drawOn(c, 100,600)
c.save()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackOverFlow. Please provide some explanation about the code. And read [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)